# how to catch the server error JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, callback, iteration

I'm learning JavaScript, through trial and error and there are times when the server does not respond, and internally generates an `Internal Server Error (500)`, and as the errors accumulate, you begin to lag the page.

Maybe I assemble the code in the wrong way? or am I doing a bad mix of functions?

Even though I caught the 500 error with `try/catch`, and attempted to call the function `update` but I can not catch him.

Also sometimes the JSON comes in null, and sends an error.
Would it be appropriate for me to catch the error?

This is the code.

[jsfiddle.net/rocr/pa0221k6/](http://jsfiddle.net/rocr/pa0221k6/14/)

```
    var width = $('.ticker-text').width(),
    containerwidth = $('.ticker-container').width(),
    left = containerwidth;
    var timer;
$(document).ready(function(e){

//timer
function Timer(callback, delay) {
    var timerId, start, remaining = delay;

    this.pause = function() {
        window.clearTimeout(timerId);
        remaining -= new Date() - start;
    };

    this.resume = function() {
        start = new Date();
        window.clearTimeout(timerId);
        timerId = window.setTimeout(callback, remaining);
    };

    this.resume();
}


//show stock quotes    
function update() {
    var query = "select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol = ";
    var symbolo = "'aapl'"; 
    var yql = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=" + escape(query+symbolo) + "&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&callback=?";
    var xhr2 = $.ajax({ 
        url: yql,
        jsonp: "myCallback",
        dataType: 'json', 
        success: function(data) {
            var keys = data.query.results.quote;
            $("#a").html(keys.LastTradePriceOnly);
            $("#b").html(keys.LastTradePriceOnly);
            update();
        }, 
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            //console.log(xhr.status + " , " +thrownError);
            //console.log('Request Status: ' + xhr.status + ' Status Text: ' + xhr.statusText + ' ' + xhr.responseText);
            update();
        },
        statusCode: {
            500: function() {
                console.log( "Error 500" );
                alert( "Error 500" );
                update();
            }
        },
        timeout: 3000
    });

}


//move div    
function tick() {
        if(--left < -width){
            left = containerwidth;
        }
        $(".ticker-text").css("margin-left", left + "px");
        //setTimeout(tick, 16);
        timer = new Timer(tick, 16);
      }
      tick();
      update();

        $("#b").hover(function(){
        timer.pause();
        $("#b").css("background-color", "yellow");
        },function(){
        timer.resume();
        $("#b").css("background-color", "pink");
        });

});
```

Comment: When there is an ajax error, the error callback is executed, that's how you catch it.

Comment: You can read the arguments of the error callback to know more about the error that occurred. Note that the second argument is not `ajaxOptions` but a text status. The page gets laggy probably because you resend the request on failure, over and over...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the ajax request is not processed, with the try, again to process up display in the DOM.

```
success: function(data) {
  try{
    var keys = data.query.results.quote;
    var keys = data.query.results.quote;
    $("#a").html(keys.LastTradePriceOnly);
    $("#b").html(keys.LastTradePriceOnly);
    update();
  }
}
```